# Labelling the points in the grid

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, grids

I am trying to construct a grid using tikzpicture, but with labels at (0,0), (0,1), (0,2) etc, something like this

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw[step=1cm,lightgray,very thin] (0,0) grid (5,5);
\filldraw[gray] (0,0) node {\tiny $(0,0)$};
\filldraw[gray] (0,1) node {\tiny $(0,1)$};
\filldraw[gray] (1,0) node {\tiny $(1,0)$};
\filldraw[gray] (1,1) node {\tiny $(1,1)$};
\filldraw[gray] (2,0) node {\tiny $(2,0)$};
%... and so on ...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Example]

However, it takes too much time to write nodes. Is there a simpler way to label the points? I imagined it should be something like

```
\foreach \x in {0, 1, ..., 5}
\foreach \y in {0,...,5}
node {\tiny $(\x,\y)$}
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \x in {1,...,7}
            \foreach \y in {1,...,5}
                \fill (\x,\y) circle[radius=1pt] node[above right] {\tiny $(\x,\y)$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: nodes and coordinates]

Or on a grid like in your picture:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[gray!50] (0,0) grid (7,5);
        \foreach \x in {0,...,7}
            \foreach \y in {0,...,5}
                \node at (\x,\y) {\tiny $(\x,\y)$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: nodes and coordinates 2]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,calc}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
        \draw[gray!30] (-3,-3) grid (3,3);
        \draw[-latex,blue] (-3.4,0)--(3.4,0) node[right] (x) {\footnotesize $x$};
        \draw[-latex,blue] (0,-3.4)--(0,3.4) node[above] (y) {\footnotesize $y$};
        \foreach \i in {-3,-2,...,3}{
            \foreach \j in {-3,-2,...,3}{
                %\pgfmathsetmacro\h{int(\i+\j)};
                \filldraw[black] (\i,\j) circle(.8pt);
                \node[blue,right] at (\i,\j+.1) (\i) {\tiny (\i,\j)};
                
            }
        } 
    \end{tikzpicture}     
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]